# Properties of a Sobolev bound

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, numerical-analysis-of-pde

I am interested in computing 
$$
A:=\inf_{f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^3)}\frac{||K^{\frac{1}{4}}f||_2^2}{||f||_{\frac{5}{2}}^2}
$$
where $K:=-\Delta+1$. We call $f_c$ the function that saturates the bound.

I would like to know if $f_c$ is a symmetric decreasing non-negative smooth real function, i.e.

- $f_c\in \mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)$
- $\exists \tilde{f}_c$ such that for every $\mathbf{r}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ one has $\;f_c(\mathbf{r})=\tilde{f}_c(||\mathbf{r}||_2)$
- $\tilde{f}_c(r)\in\mathbb{R}^+$ for every $r\in[0,\infty)$
- $\tilde{f}_c(r_1)\ge \tilde{f}_c(r_2)\,$  for  $\,0\le r_1\le r_2<\infty$

Comment: [This paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.01741.pdf) by Boulenger and Lenzmann uses the Schwarz symmetrization in Fourier space to obtain the analogous result for the biLaplacian. (See Appendix A). Can it be that the same technique can be applied to your case, maybe? HTH

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I am not sure. Looking at the paper in the proof it is used that $u^p = \mathcal{F} ( \mathcal{F}^{-1} u * \mathcal{F}^{-1}u * \cdots * \mathcal{F}^{-1}u)$. This doesn't work so well when $p$ is not an integer (as in the case here).